# Can't connect to bitcoin lightning node

Tags: lightning-network, nodes

Am trying to connect to https://1ml.com/node/02671251b5678771514df8f26cc01508606d697ae8cad38063f84becbd359b189f

From eclair app https://i.stack.imgur.com/guGGU.jpg   it keeps saying failed to open channel: Ask timed out on [Actor[akka://system/user/$i#-242463098

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also can't connect to that node. It simply seems like it is offline. Node explorers like 1ml don't keep track in Realtime if nodes are online. Did you talk to the owner of that node?

Comment: Yep, the owner said that its all connected and ready to go. Owner is running vpn on his computer, does that play a role?

Comment: The owner has to open port 9735 on his/her firewall. Some people miss this.. If they don't they can connect to other nodes but can't have incoming connections

Comment: They did open the port! I think it works now.

Comment: It was the port.. now there is a new problem... remote channel message  unreasonable to self delay = 2016 (max=200).. what does this mean?